# ios - getting raw multitouch x,y position

Tags: ios

I'm porting a windows touch application that has a built-in proprietary gesture system, and one of the requirements is I **MUST** use it.  This gestures system takes a series of x,y points (one for each touch point), and infers gestures from these raw points.

I've never done this in iOS before, and wondered what the best (only???) way is to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Touches Began:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    touchLocation.x; // x coord
    touchLocation.y; // y coord
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift:

Make sure your ViewController implements UIGestureRecognizerDelegate:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{...}
```

Inside the ViewController override the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    if let touch: UITouch = touches.first as? UITouch{
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view) as CGPoint
        touchLocation.x
        touchLocation.y
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    //When gesture ends
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch: UITouch = touches.first as? UITouch{
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view) as CGPoint
        touchLocation.x
        touchLocation.y
    }
}
```